# Efficiently rendering many select boxes on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a web application that makes heavy use of grids with select dropdowns for data entry. The grid consists of rows of select boxes. In some situations, there can be hundreds of select boxes on the page at the same time.

At the moment, I render the grid similar to the method below:

```
function render(jsonData) {
    var html = [];
    $.each(jsonData.Rows, function (i, row) {
        html.push('<tr data-id="', row.Id, '"><td>');
        renderSelect(html, globalVar.ArrayX, row.ValueX);
        html.push('</td><td>');
        renderSelect(html, globalVar.ArrayY, row.ValueY);
        html.push('</td><td>');
        ...
        html.push('</tr>');
    });
    $('tbody#container').html(html.join(''));
}

function renderSelect(html, set, selectedValue) {
    html.push('<select>');
    $.each(set, function (i, item) {
        html.push('<option value="', item.Id, '"', item.Id === selectedValue ? ' selected="1"' : '', '>', item.Name, '</option>');
    });
    html.push('</select>');
}
```

Most of the select boxes have the same options, only with different selected items per row (so I can't simply cache the select box html).

Performance is not terrible, Chrome renders the grid in 1 second and FF and IE in about 2. Still I'm wondering, if there may be a more memory/performance efficient alternative to create these select boxes, maybe some way to reference them instead of re-creating them for every row?

Comment: not tested but instead of html.push(.. why not just simple text variable of html += .. No join at the end.

Comment: @vlzvl String concatenation is slightly faster for modern browsers, but much slower for older browsers (IE<8). I'll give it a try anyway.

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jwx6C/3/ to play around with based on your code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the *select* once and use clone to place it where you need it.  If the HTML structure is literally the same, all you'd have to do after that is select the appopropriate value for each *select*

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Your other alternative is to create an html array for the *select* once before your *each* statement, join it into a string, and inside the *each* statement apply it to your the rest of your html picking your the selected *option* after it's been added. (I hope that made sense.)

Either way writing your row and select box before hand, cloning it (or copying the string) for each loop, and selecting the *option* separately for each, will be your most performant option.

Here is one possible solution using clone.  It doesn't leverage the performance of manipulating strings over appends, but you can come up with an alternate version for your purposes.

```
// construct your html ahead of time
var rowHtml = [];
rowHtml.push('<tr"><td>');
rowHtml.push('<select>');
$.each(globalVar.ArrayX, function (i, item) {
    rowHtml.push('<option value="', item.Id, '"', '>', item.Name, '</option>');
});
rowHtml.push('</select>');
rowHtml.push('</td><td>');
$.each(globalVar.ArrayY, function (i, item) {
    rowHtml.push('<option value="', item.Id, '"', '>', item.Name, '</option>');
});
rowHtml.push('</select>');
rowHtml.push('</td><td>');
rowHtml.push('</tr>');
var rowTemplate = $(rowHtml.join(''));

// make a variable for the container once so we can save time performing the DOM lookup
var container = $('tbody#container');

$(jsonData.Rows).each(function (i, row) {
    // since I have to do lookups I've chosen to manipulate attributes using jquery
    // this should move quickly now that we are just cloning
    var clone = rowTemplate.clone();
    clone.attr("data-id", row.Id);
    $("select option[value=" + row.ValueX + "]", clone).attr("selected", "selected");
    container.append(clone);
});
```

Another alternative, if you don't want to do jquery cloning and lookups would be to do string manipulation where you look for the index of the *value="X"* statement and insert your *selected=selected*.

Comment: I'll try to adapt this to my situation. One thing: not every row will have exactly the same select boxes, so I will not be able to use a single row template.

Comment: This technique is going to hit the DOM repeatedly. If you make a small change, such as putting the clones into a non DOM object, and then push that one finished object into the container, you would have better reflow. Just be wary anytime you have a tight loop with DOM operations. String manipulations are faster, but highly prone to human error and maintainability issues. Great answer either way.

Comment: Also, if you are making a rather large grid, use "loop unrolling" to improve your loops. I'd suggest unrolling each row, and looping on the rows as an implementation of that technique for your purposes.

Comment: Because of some changes in requirements I went with a slightly different solution, however I'll accept this answer as it helped me along the way.